# Контейнерный класс List, iterator, Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0x00000005"

Tags: c++, база-данных, итераторы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include<clocale>
#include<iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Kvartira
{
     string raion;
     int kolvokom;
     int plosh;
     int itash;

};
struct KvartiraI
{
     string raion2;
     int kolvokom2;
     int plosh2;
     int itash2;
};

typedef list<Kvartira> KvartiraList;
typedef list<KvartiraI> KvartiraListI;
typedef list<Kvartira>::const_iterator ConstIterKvartiraList;
typedef list<KvartiraI>::const_iterator ConstIterKvartiraListI;




void Print(const KvartiraList& List)
{
    ifstream file("isk.txt");
    cout<<file.rdbuf();
    cout<<endl;
}

char MainMenu()
{
    system("cls");  

    cout << "меню:" <<endl;
    cout << "\t 1. добавить заявку" << endl;
    cout << "\t 2. напечатать весь list" << endl;

    char item = 0;
    cin >> item;

    return item;
}
 KvartiraI DataInputI(const KvartiraListI& ListI)
 {
     std::ofstream
    fout("isk.txt",std::ios::app);
    KvartiraI kvartiraI;
    getline(std::cin, kvartiraI.raion2);
    cout << "этаж : ";
    cin >> kvartiraI.itash2;
    cout << "площадь: ";
    cin >> kvartiraI.plosh2;
    cout << "кол-во комнат: ";
    cin >> kvartiraI.kolvokom2;
    fout<<"район ";
    fout<<kvartiraI.raion2;
    fout<<" этаж ";
    fout<<kvartiraI.itash2;
    fout<<" площадь ";
    fout<<kvartiraI.plosh2;
    fout<<" количество комнат ";
    fout<<kvartiraI.kolvokom2;
    fout<<std::endl;
    fout.close();
    return kvartiraI;
 }
Kvartira DataInput(const KvartiraList& List)// Ввод данных
{
    std::ofstream
    fout("isk.txt",std::ios::app);
    Kvartira kvartira;
    cout << "район: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(std::cin, kvartira.raion);
    cout << "этаж : ";
    cin >> kvartira.itash;
    cout << "площадь: ";
    cin >> kvartira.plosh;
    cout << "кол-во комнат: ";
    cin >> kvartira.kolvokom;
    cout << "район: ";
    cin.ignore();
    fout<<"район ";
    fout<<kvartira.raion;
    fout<<" этаж ";
    fout<<kvartira.itash;
    fout<<" площадь ";
    fout<<kvartira.plosh;
    fout<<" количество комнат ";
    fout<<kvartira.kolvokom<< '\n';
    fout<<std::endl;
    fout.close();
    return kvartira;
}

int main()
{
KvartiraList List;
KvartiraListI ListI; 
KvartiraList kvartiraList;
KvartiraListI kvartiraListI;
Kvartira kvartira;
KvartiraI kvartiraI;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    size_t n = 0;
    for(ConstIterKvartiraList iKvartira = List.begin(); iKvartira != List.end();++iKvartira){
        for(ConstIterKvartiraListI iKvartira=ListI.begin();iKvartira!=ListI.end();++iKvartira){
            if(kvartira.raion==kvartiraI.raion2 && kvartira.itash==
            kvartiraI.itash2 && kvartira.kolvokom==kvartiraI.kolvokom2 &&
            kvartira.plosh>=(kvartiraI.plosh2)*1.1||kvartira.plosh<=(kvartiraI.plosh2)*1.1||kvartira.plosh==kvartiraI.plosh2){
                cout<<"вариант найден";
            }
        }}
    char answer = 'y';
    while (answer == 'y')
    {
        switch (MainMenu())
        {
        case '1':
           kvartiraList.push_front(DataInput(kvartiraList));
           kvartiraListI.push_front(DataInputI(kvartiraListI));
           //poisk(kvartiraList);
            break;
        case '2':
            Print(kvartiraList);
            break;
        default:
            cout << "такого пункта не существует." << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << "нажмите'y'для возврата в меню\nнажмите другую клавишу,чтобы выйти ";
        cin >> answer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а что это за переопределение main? Это же запрещено.

Comment: Сведения о каждой квартире содержат: количество комнат, площадь, этаж, район. Программа должна обеспечивать выбор с помощью меню и выполнение одной из следующих функций:

• ввод заявки на обмен;

• поиск в картотеке подходящего варианта: при совпадении требований и предложений по количеству комнат и этажности и различии по показателю «пло-щадь» в пределах 10% выводится соответствующая карточка и удаляется из списка, в противном случае поступившая заявка включается в картотеку;

• вывод всей картотеки.

Comment: окей, а как ее определить, если я даже скомпилировать ее не могу. Нужен воспроизводимый код.

Comment: А зачем две разных, но идентичных структуры?...

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch ой, и правда проблема в этом была

Comment: @Harry одна структура для имеющийхся квартир, другая для искомых квартир, следовательно я сделал 2 листа, по которым уже и ищу схожие варианты

Comment: for(ConstIterKvartiraList iKvartira = List.begin(); iKvartira != List.end();++iKvartira){
  for(ConstIterKvartiraListI iKvartira=ListI.begin();iKvartira!=ListI.end();++iKvartira){
   if(kvartira.raion==kvartiraI.raion2 && kvartira.itash==
   kvartiraI.itash2 && kvartira.kolvokom==kvartiraI.kolvokom2 &&
   kvartira.plosh>=(kvartiraI.plosh2)*1.1||kvartira.plosh<=(kvartiraI.plosh2)*1.1||kvartira.plosh==kvartiraI.plosh2) сравнения работают как-то не правильно, не понимаю в чём проблема

Comment: Зачем? Начнутся проблемы, связанные с тем, что это *разные* типы, хотя тип-то один и тот же! Вы де не создаете при работе с арифметикой разные арифметические типы для каждой переменной! Вы этим только ищете приключений на свою.. голову...

Comment: @Harry я немного не понимаю как работают итераторы, поэтому не знаю как сделать сравнение данных о 2-ух квартирах из одной структуры